# Cannot understand the date output of query in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have inserted data into a table of which there is a column named **current_date** of type
**date** and current_date is **'2014-01-29'**. But the problem is that whenever I am querying the table like this:

```
select *from tab;
```

It is showing current_date as '2014-01-29' but while I am querying like

```
select current_date from tab;
```

It is showing '2014-01-29'. I cannot understand why it is coming though I have set its value as '2014-01-29'.

Comment: You have mentioned the same output for both queries.

Comment: What's the issue here ?

Comment: current_date is a sql keyword and not allowed to be kept as table name or column name, try `current_date` instead `select \`current_date\` from tab;`

Comment: `CURRENT_DATE` is reserved keyword in mysql (synonym for function call `CURRENT_DATE()`), so if you are querying field wrap the name in backticks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
select current_date, `current_date` from tab;
```

and mind the backticks here: `

Answer (score 0):

`CURRENT_DATE` is a SQL Reserved Keyword and not allowed to be kept as table name or column name

Try `current_date` instead

```
select `current_date` from tab;
```

The best work around is to change the columns name to something like `currentdate` or `processed_date` or what ever but not a Reserved Keyword.